# Spring caches the object returned from a bean method

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have a following bean method:

```
@Bean
    public Queue invoiceRegenerationQueue() {
        return new Queue(configurationManager.getQueue().getInvoiceRegenerationQueueName(), true);
    }
```

and call this method somewhere in my code:

```
var binding = BindingBuilder
                .bind(invoiceRegenerationQueue())
```

I have only just discovered that when I call this method I will always get the same object instead of different objects as I expected. I expected that Spring will only inject object from the context when I use `@Autowired` annotation, but it seems it also cached the object which is returned from the bean method. I mean I debugged that and every call to that method returns the same object like as if spring intercepts calls to that method and returns an object from cache.

I tried to google but haven't been able yet to find any references to that in documentation. Why does it work so? Does anyone know where I can read about such behaviour in docs?

Comment: By default its `singleton` unless you specified bean type to something else; so I think bean got instantiated only at once & return you same object? Correct if I misunderstood.

Comment: This section in the Spring documentation explains this: [Further Information About How Java-based Configuration Works Internally](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config)

Comment: @Jesper Thanks! Why don't you make your comment an answer? I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have only just discovered that when I call this method I will always get the same object instead of different objects as I expected.

That's correct. Spring modifies `@Bean` methods in `@Configuration` classes using bytecode manipulation techniques so that multiple calls to such a method will return the same instance - which looks strange if you look at the source code itself.

The reason is that most Spring beans are singletons, and you would not want multiple instances of those beans being created when the corresponding `@Bean` method is called multiple times.

This is explained in the following section in the Spring reference documentation: [Further Information About How Java-based Configuration Works Internally](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config)

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses [ASM library](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/asm/package-info.java) for byte code manipulation.
[ConfigurationClassParser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassParser.java#L448) uses this library to load @Bean annotated methods.

[image]